# avoiding over-crowding of labels in r graphs

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am working on avoid over crowding of the labels in the following plot:

```
set.seed(123)
position <- c(rep (0,5), rnorm (5,1,0.1), rnorm (10, 3,0.1), rnorm (3, 4, 0.2), 5, rep(7,5), rnorm (3, 8,2),  rnorm (10,9,0.5),
               rep (0,5), rnorm (5,1,0.1), rnorm (10, 3,0.1), rnorm (3, 4, 0.2), 5, rep(7,5), rnorm (3, 8,2),  rnorm (10,9,0.5))
group <- c(rep (1, length (position)/2),rep (2, length (position)/2)  )
mylab <- paste ("MR", 1:length (group), sep = "")
barheight <- 0.5

y.start <- c(group-barheight/2)
y.end <- c(group+barheight/2)
mydf <- data.frame (position, group, barheight, y.start, y.end, mylab)


plot(0,type="n",ylim=c(0,3),xlim=c(0,10),axes=F,ylab="",xlab="")
#Create two horizontal lines
require(fields)
yline(1,lwd=4)
yline(2,lwd=4)
#Create text for the lines
text(10,1.1,"Group 1",cex=0.7)
text(10,2.1,"Group 2",cex=0.7)
#Draw vertical bars
lng = length(position)/2
lg1 = lng+1
lg2 = lng*2
segments(mydf$position[1:lng],mydf$y.start[1:lng],y1=mydf$y.end[1:lng])
segments(mydf$position[lg1:lg2],mydf$y.start[lg1:lg2],y1=mydf$y.end[lg1:lg2])
text(mydf$position[1:lng],mydf$y.start[1:lng]+0.65, mydf$mylab[1:lng], srt = 90)
text(mydf$position[lg1:lg2],mydf$y.start[lg1:lg2]+0.65, mydf$mylab[lg1:lg2], srt = 90)
```

You can see some areas are crowed with the labels - when x value is same or similar. I want just to display only one label (when there is multiple label at same point). For example,

mydf$position[1:5] are all 0,

but corresponding labels mydf$mylab[1:5] -

```
 MR1  MR2  MR3  MR4  MR5
```

I just want to display the first one "MR1".

Similarly the following points are too close (say the difference of 0.35), they should be considered a single cluster and first label will be displayed. In this way I would be able to get rid of overcrowding of labels. How can I achieve it ?

[image]

Comment: There is no automatic solution to these kinds of problems. One way or another you will have to fix this "by hand": either by hard coding labels for groups of close lines, or by omitting all labels and adding them afterward with an image editor.

Comment: You can substract the i postion from i-1 position data, in then make a threshold to create a cluster. Then probably display a label per cluster

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you space the labels out and add some extra lines you **can** label every marker.

```
clpl <- function(xdata, names, y=1, dy=0.25, add=FALSE){
  o = order(xdata)
  xdata=xdata[o]
  names=names[o]
  if(!add)plot(0,type="n",ylim=c(y-1,y+2),xlim=range(xdata),axes=F,ylab="",xlab="")
  abline(h=1,lwd=4)
  dy=0.25
  segments(xdata,y-dy,xdata,y+dy)
  tpos = seq(min(xdata),max(xdata),len=length(xdata))
  text(tpos,y+2*dy,names,srt=90,adj=0)
  segments(xdata,y+dy,tpos,y+2*dy)
}
```

Then using your data:

```
clpl(mydf$position[lg1:lg2],mydf$mylab[lg1:lg2])
```

gives:

[image: marking lines with callouts]

You could then think about labelling clusters underneath the main line.

I've not given much thought to doing multiple lines in a plot, but I think with a bit of mucking with my code and the add parameter it should be possible. You could also use colour to show clusters. I'm fairly sure these techniques are present in some of the clustering packages for R...

Obviously with a lot of markers even this is going to get smushed, but with a lot of clusters the same thing is going to happen. Maybe you end up labelling clusters with a this technique?

Answer (score 2):

In general, I agree with @Joran that cluster labelling can't be automated but you've said that labelling a group of lines with the first label in the cluster would be OK, so it is possible to automate some of the process.

Putting the following code after the line `lg2 = lng*2` gives the result shown in the image below:

```
clust <- cutree(hclust(dist(mydf$position[1:lng])),h=0.75)
u <- rep(T,length(unique(clust)))
clust.labels <- sapply(c(1:lng),function (i)
    {
    if (u[clust[i]])
        {
        u[clust[i]] <<- F
        as.character(mydf$mylab)[i]
        }
    else
        {
        ""
        }
    })

segments(mydf$position[1:lng],mydf$y.start[1:lng],y1=mydf$y.end[1:lng])
segments(mydf$position[lg1:lg2],mydf$y.start[lg1:lg2],y1=mydf$y.end[lg1:lg2])
text(mydf$position[1:lng],mydf$y.start[1:lng]+0.65, clust.labels, srt = 90)
text(mydf$position[lg1:lg2],mydf$y.start[lg1:lg2]+0.65, mydf$mylab[lg1:lg2], srt = 90)
```

[image: Labelled Clusters]

(I've only labelled the clusters on the lower line -- the same principle could be applied to the upper line too). The parameter `h` of `cutree()` might have to be adjusted case-by-case to give the resolution of labels that you want, but this approach is at least easier than labelling every cluster by hand.